# pgfplots multiple addplots misalignment of symbolic x axis labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Following is the code I have tried so far

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        [
            ybar,
            error bars/.cd,
            ylabel = Score,
            symbolic x coords={A1, A2, B1, B2, C1,C2,C3,C4, C5},
            xtick = {A1, A2, B1, B2, C1,C2,C3,C4, C5},
            xticklabel style = {rotate=90,anchor=east},
            bar width=14pt,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
            }
        ] 
        \addplot+ [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
            (A1,2) +- (0,0.4)
            (A2,1) +- (0,0.5) 
        };
        \addplot+ [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {

            (B1,3) +- (0,0.7) 
            (B2,2.50) +- (0,0.9) 
        };
        \addplot+ [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
            (C1,2.4) +- (0,0.3) 
            (C2,2.5) +- (0,0.4) 
            (C3,2.2) +- (0,0.9)
            (C4,2.7) +- (0,0.5)
            (C5,2.8) +- (0,0.8)
        };

        
        \legend{A Level, B Level, C Leve}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \caption{\textbf{test}}
    \label{fig:levelawareness}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives me the following graph,

[image]

How do I make the x-axis labels properly align with the bars they represent?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Add `bar shift=0pt` to your axis options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misalignment is due to the fact that PGF shifts the bars right and left according to their grouping. You have three groups, so the first group is shifted to the left and the third to the right. This might be better visualised in this modified plot of yours to which I added `(B1,1) +- (0,0.5)` in the first as well as in the third plot:

[image]

As you can see, the blue bars are always left to the ticks, while the brown bars are always shifted to the right.

In order to align everything properly, you need to set the shifting of the bars to zero using `bar shift=0pt`. This will place the labels exactly at the bars.

However, I assume that you wish to keep the distance between the three groups, for which an easy way would be to add additional symbolic coordinates.

I'd further suggest to add `ymax = 4` to align the upper line with the tick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}
        [
            ybar,
            error bars/.cd,
            ylabel = Score,
            ymax = 4,
            symbolic x coords={A1, A2, x1, B1, B2, x2, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5},
            xtick = {A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5},
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=east},
            bar width=14pt,
            enlarge x limits=0.1,
            legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
            },
            bar shift=0pt
        ] 
        \addplot+ [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
            (A1,2) +- (0,0.4)
            (A2,1) +- (0,0.5) 
        };
        \addplot+ [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
            (B1,3) +- (0,0.7) 
            (B2,2.50) +- (0,0.9) 
        };
        \addplot+ [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
            (C1,2.4) +- (0,0.3) 
            (C2,2.5) +- (0,0.4) 
            (C3,2.2) +- (0,0.9)
            (C4,2.7) +- (0,0.5)
            (C5,2.8) +- (0,0.8)
        };
        
        \legend{A Level, B Level, C Level}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \caption{\textbf{test}}
    \label{fig:levelawareness}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked!